# How to create methods with a loop in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems trying to register some methods I've created in a loop inside an object.

what I'm having is this:

```
var scriptList = {
    components : [
        'all'
    ],
    modules : [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three'
    ]
}

function interface() {
    var scope = this;

    jQuery.each(scriptList, function(key, value) {
        jQuery.each(value, function (index, name) {
            var hookValue = 'hook_'+name;

            scope.name = function(){
                window[hookValue] = jQuery('.js-'+name);
                loadAndUse(window[hookValue],key+'/'+name);
            }

            if(key === 'modules'){
                scope.name();
            }
        });
    });
}

var ui = new interface();
```

It's working and do its job, but I want to be able to reach every method I've created through the loop in this way: `console.log(ui.one());`

And I don't how to do something like that since if I do this:

```
function interface() {
    var scope = this;

    scope.one = function(){ console.log('one'); }
    scope.two = function(){ console.log('two'); }
    scope.three = function(){ console.log('three'); }
}
```

then I can access through `console.log(ui.one());` with no problem...

What am I missing? Is there some way I don't know on registering the method when you iterate them?

Comment: Note that `interface` is a future reserved keyword and using it as a function name is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've switched "interface" to "core"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scope.name` refers the the `name` property on `scope`. If you want to access a property based on a string value, you need to use square bracket notation:

```
scope[name] = function(){
    window[hookValue] = jQuery('.js-'+name);
    loadAndUse(window[hookValue],key+'/'+name);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I've changed `scope.name` to `scope[name]` and `scope.name();` to `scope[name]();` and now I get exactly what I want :)