# Adding a method to an existing object

Tags: javascript

This is an evolution of a question I asked more than a year ago: [How to create methods with a loop in jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613573/how-to-create-methods-with-a-loop-in-jquery-javascript)

I've a code that is shared with other co-workers so it's better if it changes not much. It goes like this:

```
var scriptList = {
    components : [
        'all'
    ],
    modules : [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three'
    ]
}

function core() {
    var scope = this;

    var promises = [];
    jQuery.each(scriptList, function(key, value) {
        jQuery.each(value, function (index, name) {

            var hookValue = 'hook_'+name,
                stringValue = 'string_'+name,
                argsValue = 'args_'+name;

            scope[name] = function(callback){
                window[hookValue] = jQuery('.js-'+name),
                window[stringValue] = 'js-'+name;
                window[argsValue] = arguments;

                loadAndUse(window[hookValue],key+'/'+name,callback);
            }

            if(key === 'modules'){
                scope[name]();
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, promises).then(function() {
        window.executeReady = true;
    });
}

ui = new core();

ui.exec = methodLoader;
ui.exec();
```

This code works fine, because I can use the various method I added with `ui.one` - `ui.two` and so on and is also logged in the console if I do `console.log(ui)`.

Before this code gets fired tho, I have now another block of code inside the **HTML page**, which create a method (always of the `ui` object) called `exec`:

```
window.executeReady = false;

var ui = {},
    scriptToBeLoaded = [];

var methodLoader = function(){
    var scope = this;

    this.exec = function(module, callback){
        scriptToBeLoaded.push({
            'module'    : module,
            'callback'  : callback
        });

        if(module === undefined){
            console.warn('This module does not exists. Please check the scriptList.');
        } else {
            function waitForList($context, $variable, $callback) {
                if ($context[$variable]) {
                    $callback();
                } else {
                    Object.defineProperty($context, $variable, {
                        configurable: true,
                        enumerable: true,
                        writeable: true,
                        get: function() {
                            return this['_' + $variable];
                        },
                        set: function(val) {
                            this['_' + $variable] = val;
                            $callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            waitForList(window, 'executeReady', function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < scriptToBeLoaded.length; i++) {
                    ui[scriptToBeLoaded[i].module](scriptToBeLoaded[i].callback);
                }

                scriptToBeLoaded = [];
            });
        }
    };
};

ui = new methodLoader();
```

Because of this block of code, when I `console.log(ui);` I see only the `exec` method and all of the other methods are gone. Although, the method I create in the `core()` function are executed correctly, but not present in the `ui` object.

I would like to edit the code in the HTML Page to have the `ui` object with `exec` (which is create on the html side) and the other method (that are created in the js file) all inside the `ui` object.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well the last line is "ui = new methodLoader()", so ui is basically overridden.

Comment: Basically when you use new keyword with the function call, its just the constructor function mainly used to create classes in javascript. So whenever new keyword is used with function , a new object is created  and the this keyword used in that function is binded to that new object. Hence, in  `var scope = this;
    this.exec`  this points to new object. And only exec is accessible through this object.

Comment: Ok, seems logic. Thanks. But how can I achieve what I want without declaring two "new"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new methods to existing object like this. Or you can use [jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to merge two object.

```
var ui = ui || {},
scriptToBeLoaded = [];

ui.exec = function(module, callback){
        scriptToBeLoaded.push({
            'module'    : module,
            'callback'  : callback
        });

        if(module === undefined){
            console.warn('This module does not exists. Please check the scriptList.');
        } else {
            function waitForList($context, $variable, $callback) {
                if ($context[$variable]) {
                    $callback();
                } else {
                    Object.defineProperty($context, $variable, {
                        configurable: true,
                        enumerable: true,
                        writeable: true,
                        get: function() {
                            return this['_' + $variable];
                        },
                        set: function(val) {
                            this['_' + $variable] = val;
                            $callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            waitForList(window, 'executeReady', function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < scriptToBeLoaded.length; i++) {
                    ui[scriptToBeLoaded[i].module](scriptToBeLoaded[i].callback);
                }

                scriptToBeLoaded = [];
            });
        }
    };
```